# Garbage Collector

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

i want to know the internal architecture and function of the garbage collector in dotnet in detail.. can anybody help me.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?! I would love to know the exact same thing... :-(

Answer (score 11):

.NET uses a generational garbage collector, [MSDN link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)

Comment: what ever u sent is not basics..it is some advanced and performance related article...i want some basics like how it will start and collect..that algorithm...

Comment: The article tells you a lot about the implementation. It is titled " >> Garbage Collector Basics << and Performance Hints". Did you even read it ? you wanted basics right ?

Comment: Your original post also said you wanted basics and detail..... choose one please.

Comment: The basics of GC is that "it collects unreferenced objects". Any implementation details are inevitably going to be more advanced.

Answer (score 4):

See

[Garbage Collector Basics and Performance Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the excellent suggestion to study Rotor by GvS you should also look at the following videos which talks about the some more details of the GC internals.

Also note the Rotor implementation is different from the RTM version of GC which means it is not the exact same logic in .NET, but it is good enough to get you to understand the principles.

- [Garbage Collection - Past, Present
  and Future](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Patrick-Dussud-Garbage-Collection-Past-Present-and-Future/)
- [Erik Meijer and Patrick Dussud -
  Inside Garbage Collection](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/E2E-Erik-Meijer-and-Patrick-Dussud-Inside-Garbage-Collection/)
- [CLR 4 Garbage Collector - Inside Background GC](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Maoni-Stephens-and-Andrew-Pardoe-CLR-4-Inside-Background-GC/)

Answer (score 3):

To study the source code of the Garbage Collector itself, you can download and study [the Rotor source](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D&displaylang=en), or [the Mono source](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).

There is also a nice speech on the future of the Garbage collector, that handles some internals. [You can find it here.](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT51)

Comment: Rotor uses a completely different GC though, right?